# In .net 6, how do I pass the parameter to the constructor when the service initialization comes before the configuration binding of values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I can't seem to find the solution to my exact problem, because I need to call the dependency injection before calling the builder, but this results in a new object instantiation in the controller class and the values are lost.
If I put this line right after binding, I can get an error saying cannot modify the service after it has been built.

In the older version of .net, since Startup.cs is existing, this doesn't seem to be a problem due to the separation of methods ConfigureService and Configure.

AuthenticationBind.cs

```
public class AuthenticationBind
{
    public int AuthenticationId { get; set; }
    public string AuthenticationName { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "TestAuthenticationBind": {
    "AuthenticationId": "1324556666",
    "AuthenticationName": "Test Authentication Name"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Program.cs

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationBind>();

var app = builder.Build();

AuthenticationBind tb = new AuthenticationBind();
IConfiguration configuration = app.Configuration;
configuration.Bind("TestAuthenticationBind", tb);
```

AuthenticationController.cs

```
    private readonly AuthenticationBind authenticationBind;
    public AuthenticationController(AuthenticationBind authenticationBind)
    {
        this.authenticationBind = authenticationBind;
    }
```

Also, can I use the object instance to pass to services.AddSingleton method, instead of the class itself, like below?

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<tb>();
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to have the same instance of the `AuthenticationBind` class shared across all services? You can do this with `services.AddSingleton(_ => new AuthenticationBind());`

Calling `AddSingleton<AuthenticationBind>()` *will* register the class as a singleton, but it will still be constructed by the `IServiceProvider` (but only once).

Comment: but it's producing a new instance, instead of the bound values from the appsettings file already.

Comment: If you wish to use the values from the configuration, you need to call `builder.Services.Configure<AuthenticationBind>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("TestAuthenticationBind"))` then inject `IOptions<AuthenticationBind>` into your controller

Comment: Same goes after constructing the app: just call `app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AuthenticationBind>>()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you're trying to [bind configuration values into models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#options-interfaces). You can do this by calling `IServiceCollection.Configure<T>()` - for your code, it would look like this:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<AuthenticationBind>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("TestAuthenticationBind"));
```

Afterwards, you can use the `IOptions<T>` interface in your controller to access the (bound) object:

```cs
public AuthenticationController(
  IOptions<AuthenticationBind> authOptions
)
{
  // You can access authOptions.Value here
}
```

Same goes in the startup class, you can request the `IOptions` interface like so:

```cs
var authOptions = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AuthenticationBind>>();
```